'Image' is imported from 2 files
I use for my flutter app rive animation and now I receive this error and don't know what to do
I tried to add after rive package as Image but then I get a red line under Riveanimation
I don't have any widgets package added to my page , should I added and put after as Image?

I also try to add package import 'package:image/image.dart' as Image; and I get a red line under Image.asset

Try to import shape library like import 'package:rive/src/rive_core/shapes/image.dart' hide Image;

https://imgur.com/a/NBfYLXZ

Try using different aliases for images and then import them into your projects.
That might help. Please let me know.
